# How to make a class with a member of unique_ptr work with std::move and std::swap?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a class. It has a member of unique_ptr.

```
class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> m;
};
```

I hope it works with the following statements

```
A a;
A b;
a = std::move(b);
std::swap(a, b);
```

How to make it?

**According to the comments, I have a question. Is this compiler dependent? If I do nothing, it cannot pass compilation in VC++ 2012.**

I tried before

```
struct A
{
    A() {}

    A(A&& a)
    {
        mb = a.mb;
        ma = std::move(a.ma);
    }

    A& operator = (A&& a)
    {
        mb = a.mb;
        ma = std::move(a.ma);
        return *this;
    }

    unique_ptr<int> ma;
    int mb;
};
```

But not sure if this is the best and simplest way.

Comment: You need to do precisely nothing.  It should work exactly as defined in your first example, without any user defined constructors or assignment operators.

Comment: You should follow The Rule of Zero and let the compiler generated the default move/copy assignment operators.

Comment: You [don't need to define](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b8e0d2214e) any constructors/assignment operators explicitly to get that to work. Refer to the [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html) for an explanation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Is this compiler dependent? If I do nothing, it cannot pass compilation in VC++ 2012.

Comment: @user1899020: it shouldn't be compiler dependent, but VC++ 2010 and 2012 have a serious bug where it refuses to compile this correctly.  At this rate I'm afraid they won't fix it :(  Your second block of code is _close_ to the easiest way to do it in VC++2012.  Though VC++2013 will allow the simpler standard version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is absolutely correct in C++11. But VC++ 2012 currently doesn't implement [N3053](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3053.html). As a result, the compiler does not implicitly generate move constructor or assignment operator for you. So if you stuck with VC++ 2012 you need to implement them by yourself.